# PayPal form not working in Chrome

Tags: forms, google-chrome, paypal

I have a shopping cart form. When I submit the form using FF, IE or Safari everything works fine (it's redirected to the PayPal account and shows the product description, price, and option to login for paying)

But in Chrome when submitted, it opens the PayPal HOME page.

This is the form:

```
<form id="paypalForm" name="paypalForm" action="http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="business" value="myaccount@hotmail.com"> 
    <input type="text" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="text" name="notify_url" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/ipnlib/ipn.php" />
    <input type="text" name="return" value="http://www.mywebsite.com" />
    <input type="text" name="currency_code" value="MXN" />
    <input type="text" name="upload" value="1">


        <input type="text" name="item_number_1" value="02603">
        <input type="text" name="item_name_1" value="02603 HOVER PRO 450">
        <input type="text" name="quantity_1" value="1">
        <input type="text" name="amount_1" value="14239.4">



    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

If I check the sent headers, seems fine, this is what headers options for Firebug and Chrome Developer tools shows:

Chrome

```
business:myaccount@hotmail.com
cmd:_cart
notify_url:http://www.mywebsite.com/ipnlib/ipn.php
return:http://www.mywebsite.com
currency_code:MXN
upload:1
item_number_1:02603
item_name_1:02603 HOVER PRO 450
quantity_1:1
amount_1:14239.4
```

FireFox

```
amount_1    14239.4
business    myaccount@hotmail.com
cmd _cart
currency_code   MXN
item_name_1 02603 HOVER PRO 450
item_number_1   02603
notify_url  http://www.mywebsite.com/ipnlib/ipn.php
quantity_1  1
return  http://www.mywebsite.com
upload  1
```

Answer (score 1):

FOUND IT!!!

instead of

```
<form id="paypalForm" name="paypalForm" action="http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

is:

```
<form id="paypalForm" name="paypalForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

Weird that it worked in every browser except Chrome...

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that the difference between the two is an `https` instead of `http`, notice the added `s`